# An image in my table dips and hugs to the left for some reason

Tags: html, css

I'm formatting a table on 2 rows with 3 images but the 2nd image in each row keeps dipping down and hugging to the wrong direction. I'm not sure what's causing it.

This is for an email and I'm just trying to pick apart some of the template to better fit my needs, thus all that inline CSS.. The responsiveColumn class is just for a media query just an fyi.

```
<!-- 2nd Image -->
<td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 5px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<div class="" style="">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<p style="text-align: center;">
<a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div></td></tr>
</tbody></table></td>
```

I put it in jsfiddle so you can see it more clearly. You'll see how the 2nd image in each row just dips down and moves to the left opposed to keeping everything evenly on one line

https://jsfiddle.net/9f5c2zh6/1/

Comment: Why do you have tables within tables ?

Comment: I tested [this](https://jsfiddle.net/v9Lbt7pe/2/) method via [Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/c/) and it came back with no errors. It does use inline CSS styles in the head which [isn't supported by all webmail's](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/style-element/style-in-head/).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `padding-top`

```
<td style="padding-top: 20px;padding-right: 5px;padding-bottom: 20px;padding-left: 5px;background-color: #ffffff;color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
```

Comment: I thought that was it too but that just effects the table than the image itself. As in, the image then shoots more upwards. I figured this is something with the image not centering itself. Unless all the padding is playing a part.

Comment: Nope, it's the padding. It's probably not applied consistently. You can turn it off and on using Developer tools (F12) and see.

Comment: bah okay, i was trying to mess with it but then it started shooting all over the place and affecting the ones underneath.. feel like i should just start this from scratch. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is why we avoid inline styles because it's difficult to debug, However after some fiddling around, i found some problems

**First:** certain `p` elements have the following styles, And some others don't

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**Second:** certain `td` elements have the following styles, And some others don't

```
td {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

The fix is to add the missing styles to where they belongs so everything is aligned nicely together

```css
td {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  color: #000000;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td width="100%" valign="top" style="color: #000000;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="33%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <!-- 1st Image -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div class="" style="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; color: #000000;">
                              <p style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></a>
                              </p>

                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <!-- 2nd Image -->
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 5px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div class="" style="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p style="text-align: center;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <!-- 3rd Image -->
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="33%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div style="" class="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="color: #000000;">
                              <p style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="float: right; border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<!-- end 3 column section -->


<!-- 3 column section -->
<tr>
  <td width="100%" valign="top" style="color: #000000;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="33%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <!-- 1st Image on 2nd row -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div class="" style="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; color: #000000;">
                              <p style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>

                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <!-- 2nd Image on 2nd row -->
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="34%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 5px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div class="" style="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              <p style="text-align: center;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
          <!-- 3rd Image on 2nd row -->
          <td style="background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" class="responsiveColumn" width="33%" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 0px; background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;" valign="top" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <div style="" class="">
                      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" style="word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="color: #000000;">
                              <p style="margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-top: 0; padding: 0;">
                                <a href="link.html" target="_blank"><img alt="Metro PCS" src="https://via.placeholder.com/175x150" style="float: right; border: 0px solid #000000; display: block;" width="175" height="150"></p>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```